# JQuery clone insertafter

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I cloned a html element.

```
var $clone = $('.rules-if-field-container-'+if_counter).clone(true);
```

But now I want to append a div when the div is cloned.

I tried this:

```
$clone.append('<div class="append_or_'+inc_counter+'"> </div>').insertAfter('rules-if-field-container-'+inc_counter);
```

But doesn't give me the correct result.

It gives me this result:

```
<div class="box box-warning box-solid rules-if-field-container-1"><div class="append_or_1">  </div></div>
```

But it must be like this:

```
<div class="box box-warning box-solid rules-if-field-container-1"></div>
<div class="append_or_1">  </div>
```

How can I perform a `insertAfter` when I cloned an element?

Answer (score 1):

In that case `append()` is not suitable for your needs, as it creates the content you specify as a child element of the target.

Instead you can first add the clone to the DOM, then use `after()` to add the second div. Try this:

```
$clone
  .insertAfter('.rules-if-field-container-' + inc_counter)
  .after('<div class="append_or_' + inc_counter + '"> </div>');
```

Also note that I would strongly suggest you don't use incremental class names. They quickly become a pain to maintain, and go completely against the point of classes, which is to allow grouping of related elements.

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

> The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child
>   of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the first
>   child, use .prepend()).

I think you need [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead.

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.